# how to save acf_form using ajax without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have theese three acf_form. I want to show these form one by one as well as I want to save every form on button click through ajax without page refresh. Right now it's refreshing page whenever I update. 
I will show through display none & block using js.

```
<div class="SetupNew">
            <h2>Setup Deals To Attract New Clientele</h2>
            <p>Example: buy $15 get $30 for services</p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><p id="newDealsTxt">[Click Here To Setup] </p></a></div>
            <?php acf_form($args =  array(
                                          'post_id' => $post_id,
                                          'field_groups' => array(2029),
                                          'form_attributes' => array(
                                              'id'=>'newDeals'
                                           ),
                                      ));  ?>
            <div class="SetupEx">
            <h2>Setup Deals To Bring In Clientele During Nonpeak Hours</h2>
            <p>Example: buy $15 get $30 for services Tue-Thur 9am - 2pm.</p>          
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><p id="exDealsTxt">[Click Here To Setup]</p></a></div>
            <?php  acf_form($args =  array(
                                          'post_id' => $post_id,
                                          'field_groups' => array(2047),
                                          'form_attributes' => array(
                                              'id'=>'exDeals'
                                          ),
                                      ));  ?>
            <div class="SetupFb">
            <h2>Setup $5 Off Coupon To Increase Testimonials And Sharing</h2>
            <p>Example: Leave a testimonial and get $5 off your next service.</p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><p id="fbDealsTxt">[Click Here To Setup] </p></a></div>

            <?php  acf_form($args =  array(
                                          'post_id' => $post_id,
                                          'field_groups' => array(2123),
                                          'form_attributes' => array(
                                              'id'=>'fbDeals'
                                          ),
                                      ));  ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><h2 id="backk">Back << </h2>  </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

This comes pretty late, but I had the same problem today. For reference, here's my javascript:

```
// call this function on document ready or when your ajax page is loaded
function renderPage() {
  // initialize the acf script
  acf.do_action('ready', $('body'));

  // will be used to check if a form submit is for validation or for saving
  let isValidating = false;

  acf.add_action('validation_begin', () => {
    isValidating = true;
  });

  acf.add_action('submit', ($form) => {
    isValidating = false;
  });

  $('.acf-form').on('submit', (e) => {
    let $form = $(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
    // if we are not validating, save the form data with our custom code.
    if( !isValidating ) {
      // lock the form
      acf.validation.toggle( $form, 'lock' );
      $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        method: 'post',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: () => {
          // unlock the form
          acf.validation.toggle( $form, 'unlock' );
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```